# Emmet nested element issue

Tags: html, emmet

I'm sorry that I can't think a creative question title. I'm trying Emmet and the HTML I want is:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Hello</button>
```

I tried below Emmet expression:

```
button.btn.btn-warning>span.glyphicon.glyphicon-search{ Hello}
```

However the output from it is:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"> Hello</span></button>
```

Is is possible for Emmet to get what I want?

Answer (score 4):

You have to put `+` before `{ Hello}` to make it a sibling node:

```
button.btn.btn-warning>span.glyphicon.glyphicon-search+{ Hello}
```

See http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/#text-